# Minimizing two matrices

Tags: math

I have tow matrices C_model and C_measure and i want to minimize the difference between them where sigma_i is the error variance of element i and C_ij is each element in the matrix

I tried the following:

`\chi^2  =\sum_{i,j} \frac{(C_{model,i,j}-\hat{C_{i,j}})^2}{\sigma^2_{i}}  = \sum_{i,j} (\Delta C_{i,j})^2 W_{i} = (\Delta C)(\Delta C)^{T}`

I want to check whether this formula is correct mathematically, and why i can replace this term

\sum_{i,j} (\Delta C_{i,j})^2 W_{i} by
this term ? (\Delta C)(\Delta C)^{T}, i took it from reference book but i do not understand the math behind it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't seem related to programming at all, and is pure math.

Comment: Also, unlike SE sites like the math one, SO doesn't have LaTeX rendering, so your formula is difficult to read.

Comment: @ThomasJager Where can i ask such questions ? in which websites